# Can I us AWS SSO as an external IdP in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sso

I actually have done this before but can't figure out the settings I used ) :

Basically I want to setup AWS SSO as an external IdP for Cognito. I've done this before via SAML but I can't remember what values I used for the Application settings in the AWS SSO part, I thought it was:

- Application ACS URL: https://{full custom domain}/saml2/idpresponse
- Application SAML audience {cognito userpool id}

But that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the Cognito Flow it tells you all the required urls you'll need. These urls are specific your account/user pool. The flow is:

`Add Identity Provider`
[image]

Then select `SAML`, and enter the values in the first screen:
[image]

After that you'll be led down what the values you'll need for the AWS SSO application side.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-iam-integration) is a bit old but it can be used as a reference to use AWS Identity manager as an external provider for Cognito.

In short, once you've created your basic cognito user pool, you'll get your cognito domain (or custom domain if you've set one).

On the IAM Identity Center, select **Applications**, then choose **Add a custom SAML 2.0 application**, assign a name and a description. Under **IAM Identity Center metadata**, make a note of the **IAM Identity Center SAML metadata file** URL because you'll need it while configuring Cognito.
Skip the **Application properties** section, under **Application metadata**, select **Manually type your metadata values**, then:

- For **Application ACS URL**, enter the Amazon **Cognito domain** name you've got from cognito followed by `/saml2/idpresponse`, for example: `https://my-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse`
- For **Application SAML audience**, enter the Amazon Cognito user pool service provider URN. Just append the cognito user pool ID to `urn:amazon:cognito:sp:`. For example, if your cognito user pool id is `us-east-1_nOJn1ZE4a` you'll set: `**urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-1_nOJn1ZE4a`.